# Writing a push method for a Stack in C++

Tags: c++, stack, push

So I'm trying to write a push method for a Stack in C++ and I can't for the life of me get it to work. Here is what I have so far (and please forgive the mess, I've been trying to bug fix this all day)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ItemInStack
{
  string data; //where we're keeping the "stuff"
  ItemInStack *next; //address to where we're going next
};

class Stack{
  private:
    ItemInStack *head;
    int data;

  public:
    Stack(){ //constructor
      head = NULL;
    }

    void pushMethod(string newData){
      ItemInStack *tmp = new ItemInStack;
      tmp->data = newData;
      tmp->next = head; //set next to head since the new item is the new head/top of stack

      if(head == NULL) //checking if the first set of data
      {
        head = tmp;
        cout<<"BUG FIX: \ndata = "<<tmp->data<<"\nhead = "<<head<<"\nnext = "<<tmp->next<<endl<<endl;
      }

      else //the rest of the list, aka the majority of the program
      {
        head->next = tmp;
        head = head->next;
        cout<<"BUG FIX: \ndata = "<<tmp->data<<"\nhead = "<<head<<"\nnext = "<<tmp->next<<endl<<endl;
      }   
    }

    void display()
    {
      ItemInStack*tmp; //make a tmp to hold stuff
      tmp=head; 

      cout<<"\n~~START DISPLAY~~\n";

      //Here's where im tring to bug-fix
      cout<<"-First\ntmp->data = "<<tmp->data<<"\nhead = "<<head<<"\ntmp->next = "<<tmp->next<<endl<<endl;
      head = tmp->next;

      cout<<"-Second\ntmp->data = "<<tmp->data<<"\nhead = "<<head<<"\ntmp->next = "<<tmp->next<<endl<<endl;
      head = tmp->next; 

      cout<<"-Third\ntmp->data = "<<tmp->data<<"\nhead = "<<head<<"\ntmp->next = "<<tmp->next<<endl<<endl;
      head = tmp->next;
      //end of bug fix attempt

  /* while loop for display once bug-fix is complete
      while(tmp->next != NULL)
      {
        cout<<"\ntmp->next = "<<tmp->next<<"\nhead = "<<head<<endl;

        cout << tmp->data << endl; //display
        tmp = tmp->next; //move next down the chain
      }
      */
    }
};

int main()
{
  Stack a; //creating an instance of the Stack class
  a.pushMethod("Old First");
  a.pushMethod("New First");
  a.pushMethod("Extra New First");
  a.display();  //show me the money
  return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell I'm getting the next address to point to the previous head correctly, because in my BUG FIX cout it is showing the next for old first to be 0 (NULL), then the next for New First is the same address as the head of Old First, and the next for Extra New First is the same address as the head for New First. However when I try and print it in the display function I can't seem to move down the list correctly.

My teacher said he thinks (but wasn't sure) that somehow my next pointer is being changed before it reaches display. Any advice, help, etc would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: In your commented out `while` loop, you'll probably want to check `tmp != NULL` instead of `tmp->next != NULL`, otherwise you won't print the last item.

Comment: Just some style and code issues: `Stack::data` is never used, so remove it. The accessible element in a stack is usually called `top`, not `head`. And `pushMethod` is needlessly verbose. It's obviously a method. Just call it `push`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set the `head` pointer to the last inserted node each time you push back. This wouldn't be a problem except once you set the head pointer there is no way to go back along the list (for instance when printing or deleting the top node). The correct way to insert would be to set the `next` of the new node to the current head and then set the `head` to the new node.

```
tmp->next = head;
head = tmp;
```

Now the head always points to the last inserted node but its `next` pointer points back towards the rest of the list.

Comment: omg!! my dude, thank you!! I see what you're saying. Idk what I was thinking XD
Sincerely, I appreciate the help! *thumbs up*

Answer (score 0):

This code part

```
if(head == NULL) //checking if the first set of data
{
  head = tmp;
  cout<<"BUG FIX: \ndata = "<<tmp->data<<"\nhead = "<<head<<"\nnext = "<<tmp->next<<endl<<endl;
}
else //the rest of the list, aka the majority of the program
{
  head->next = tmp;
  head = head->next;
  cout<<"BUG FIX: \ndata = "<<tmp->data<<"\nhead = "<<head<<"\nnext = "<<tmp->next<<endl<<endl;
}
```

should be

```
head = tmp;
cout<<"BUG FIX: \ndata = "<<tmp->data<<"\nhead = "<<head<<"\nnext = "<<tmp->next<<endl<<endl;
```

head -> nullptr becomes head -> tmp -> nullptr. 
Or head -> tail becomes head -> tmp -> tail. Regardless tail is nullptr or not.